# How to group ID's by score in different types in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
ID    Type    Score
-------------------
5      1       100
8      1       200
3      1       300 
8      2       100
3      2       200
5      2       300
```

How do I sort them by descending score (to give them a ranking for that Type) and then create a table which a column for each Type where the ID's positions are shown such as:

```
ID    Type1    Type2
--------------------
3      1st      2nd
5      3rd      1st
8      2nd      3rd
```

So far I am able able to do this by explicitly declaring the Type number such as:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Score DESC) AS Rank, ID
FROM Table
WHERE Type = 1
```

This returns a rank for each ID when Type is 1.

How do I join this together with the same result when Type is 2? And how do I do this for any number of types?

Comment: Replace `WHERE` with appropriate `PARTITION BY`, make `PIVOT`.

Comment: What if there is a tie?  What is the number of 2s in not equal the number of 1s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to tackled this. My choice would be to use conditional aggregation. Here is how this might look. If you need a dynamic number of types that can be accomplished also but is a little trickier.

```
declare @Something table
(
    ID int
    , Type int
    , Score int
)
;

insert @Something values
(5, 1, 100)
, (8, 1, 200)
, (3, 1, 300) 
, (8, 2, 100)
, (3, 2, 200)
, (5, 2, 300)
;

with SortedValues as
(
    select *
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Type order by Score)
    from @Something
)
select ID
    , Type1 = max(case when Type = 1 then RowNum end)
    , Type2 = max(case when Type = 2 then RowNum end)
from SortedValues
group by ID
order by ID
;
```

**-- EDIT --**

I realized you said you need to have this work for any number of Types. Most people around SO like to ue a dynamic pivot. I personally find the syntax for pivot to be very obtuse. I prefer to build a dynamic version of conditional aggregation for this type of thing. Here is how you can use dynamic sql to generate the results for any number of Types.

Note I had to switch to using a temp table because a table variable would not be available in the scope of the dynamic sql unless it is declared inside the dynamic sql.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') is not null
    drop table #Something

create table #Something
(
    ID int
    , Type int
    , Score int
)
;

insert #Something values
(5, 1, 100)
, (8, 1, 200)
, (3, 1, 300) 
, (8, 2, 100)
, (3, 2, 200)
, (5, 2, 300)
;

declare @StaticPortion nvarchar(2000) = 
    'with SortedValues as
    (
        select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Type order by Score) as RowNum
        from #Something
    )
    select ID';

declare @DynamicPortion nvarchar(max) = '';

with E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
cteTally(N) AS 
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E2
)

select @DynamicPortion = @DynamicPortion + 
    ', MAX(Case when Type = ' + CAST(N as varchar(6)) + ' then RowNum end) as Type' + CAST(N as varchar(6)) + CHAR(10)
from cteTally t
where t.N <= 
(
    select Count(distinct Type)
    from #Something
)


declare @FinalStaticPortion nvarchar(2000) = ' from SortedValues
group by ID
order by ID';

select @StaticPortion + @DynamicPortion + @FinalStaticPortion

declare @SqlToExecute nvarchar(max) = @StaticPortion + @DynamicPortion + @FinalStaticPortion;

select @SqlToExecute
exec sp_executesql @SqlToExecute
```